# CoffeeScript reduce skips values that are the same

Tags: coffeescript

I am using CoffeeScript to aggregate elements from a list into a combined object. However, when I have two values that are the same, one of the values gets left out. Instead of skipping one of these values, how can I get their sum?

```
metals = [
  { metal: 'silver', amount: 10 }
  { metal: 'gold',   amount: 16 }
  { metal: 'iron',   amount: 17 }
  { metal: 'iron',   amount:  3 }
]

reduction = metals.reduce (x, y) ->
  x[y.metal]= y.amount
  x
, {}

console.log reduction
# => { silver: 10, gold: 16, iron: 3 }, but I  would like to get iron: 20
```

here is a jsfiddle to help solve the problem https://jsfiddle.net/822trwez/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum things then you have to say so:

```
reduction = metals.reduce (x, y) ->
  x[y.metal] = (x[y.metal] ? 0) + y.amount
  x
, { }
```

The `x[y.metal] ? 0` is just saying "if `x[y.metal]` is defined then use it, otherwise use `0`". You could also say:

```
reduction = metals.reduce (x, y) ->
  x[y.metal] = (x[y.metal] || 0) + y.amount
  x
, { }
```

since you don't care about falsey values for `x[y.metal]` such as `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, or `undefined`; in your case you can convert all those to zero.

You could also be more explicit about what you're doing:

```
reduction = metals.reduce (x, y) ->
    x[y.metal]  = 0 if(y.metal !of x)
    x[y.metal] += y.amount
    x
, {}
```

The `x[y.metal] = 0 if(y.metal !of x)` just initializes `x[y.metal]` to zero if `x` doesn't have a `y.metal` property already. You could also use `unless` if you don't like `!of`:

```
reduction = metals.reduce (x, y) ->
    x[y.metal]  = 0 unless(y.metal of x)
    x[y.metal] += y.amount
    x
, {}
```

Keep in mind that all `reduce` does is runs the function you give it and feeds the function's output back to itself so:

```
[1,2,3].reduce f, i
```

is just:

```
f(f(f(i, 1), 2), 3)
```

What the function `f` does with its inputs and what it returns is up to you.

Comment: thank you for the great answer! this solves my problem and any future problems that i might have with reduce. thanks!

Comment: What are your recommendations for working with bigDecimal in rails 4.1.6 when using as_json to retrieve the data? In this case, I was using decimal, and as_json was returning the data in quotes.

Comment: You're probably better off converting it to an integer and letting the client format it as needed.

Comment: I ended up using the active support gem [link](https://github.com/rails/activesupport-json_encoder) and did this:  ActiveSupport.encode_big_decimal_as_string = false. I read some opinionated comments and posts about the topic and thought I would share to see if there are any serious issues that I may have not thought about. Ayways, thanks for sharing your knowledge and helping me out.